# What is Homogeneity and isotropy in terms of thermodynamic system ?Also the difference between them?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

I searched about it on web but was not able to find the difference between isotropy and homogeneity in terms of a Thermodynamic system.
So, I wanted to know the difference between them in a thermodynamics system.

Answer (score 0):

*Homogenuity* is invariance of properties in respect to translation in space, whereas *isotropy* is their invariance in respect to different directions, i.e. in respect to rotation. In a thermodynamic systems this means corresponding invariance of preassure, temperature, specific heat, etc. If by *thermodynamic* one means a system from statistical physics, containing randomly moving molecules or something similar, then *homogenuity* and *isotropy* are understood as applying to the average quantities or statistical distributions.

For example, the ideal gas in a gravity field will have its properties unchanged when moving along the equipotential lines of the gravitational potential, but not when moving vertically (i.e., across these lines).